# Access CSS file from Public Folder without Route

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to serve a css file (app.css) from the public folder of an express app with `app.use(express.static("public"));` which works fine when i access the home route at `/` and loads app.css correctly

However, when I access the app at /posts, it tries to loads the css file from /posts/app.css which does not exist in the public folder.

How do I get express to access the css file from /app.css in the public folder instead of the app trying to access the css file from /posts/app.css

here is the full code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("home")
})

app.get("/posts",function(req,res){
    var arrPosts =[
        {title: "first title", author:"first author"},
        {title: "second title", author:"second author"},
        {title: "third title", author:"third author"},

    ];
    res.render("posts", {posts:arrPosts})
})

app.listen(3000, process.env.IP, function() { 
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000'); 
});
```

HTML file for posts.ejs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">

<%for(var i=0; i< posts.length;i++){ %>
<li><%= posts[i].title %> - <strong><%= posts[i].author%></strong></li>

<% } %>

</br>

<% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>

<li><%= post.title %> - <strong><%= post.author%></strong></li>

<% }) %>
```

Comment: What is "it" in "it tries to loads the css"? Because really all that tells you is that you should fix your HTML so that your css link `href` attributes start with `/`: don't load your CSS on a locally relative URL when your app will work on arbitrarily deep routes. Your asset dir has a fixed location, point to that.

Comment: Nifty username. The path in your css include should start with `/`, like `/app.css`. You could also use a virtual path like `app.use(express.static('assets'))` and `/assets/app.css`.

Comment: yea, all i needed was a / in the href. thanks